# How can create a color progressbar in delphi?

Tags: delphi, updatepanel-progressbar

i want to create a color progress bar in delphi language within use by **XPMan** component (it is : with win xp style).

what do i do?

what code using?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583266/help-me-to-create-a-color-progressbar-in-delphi

Comment: It is best to close the other one, because this question belongs to a registered user.

Answer (score 7):

With themes enabled you cannot change the color of the progressbar. With themes disabled you can change the color by sending a PBM_SETBARCOLOR message to the control.

Since you want a to change the color of your themed progressbar, you have to do all the drawing yourself or use a 3rd party progressbar that mimics a themed progressbar where you can change the color.

Comment: FWIW, TMS Controls have lots of nice progressbars, if you want a drop-in 3rd-party solution.

Answer (score 1):

Same opinion as The_Fox.
If you want a free 3rd party, here is one : http://rmklever.com/?p=138

Answer (score 1):

```
uses
  commctrl

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ProgressBar1.Brush.Color := clGreen;
  SendMessage(ProgressBar1.Handle, PBM_SETBARCOLOR, 0, clYellow);
  ProgressBar1.Position := 50;
end;
```